# Python script has to create a 'pdf' when it executes but I keep getting permission denied from ubuntu terminal when i run the script.?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ubuntu-14.04, graphviz

Code Snippet :

```
dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(classifier,out_file=dot_data,
                        feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                        class_names=iris.target_names,
                        )
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_pdf("iris_classification.pdf") # I think this line is not getting executed ...
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testt.py", line 30, in <module>
    graph.write_pdf("iris_classification.pdf")
  File "/home/manish/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1809, in <lambda>
    lambda path, f=frmt, prog=self.prog : self.write(path, format=f, prog=prog))
  File "/home/manish/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot.py", line 1895, in write
    dot_fd = file(path, "w+b")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'iris_classification.pdf'
```

I have tried sudo python2 testt.py but no modules work with sudo (has it got something do with $PATH ? but the anaconda path is still there on $PATH variable even after sudo so why does not it work with sudo ?)
and changing the permission to 7 and executing ./testt.py is not working either.

Comment: What kind of IOError? What user is running the script? Does that user have write permissions in the directory? You haven't really given us much to go on.

Comment: Which distribution are you running?

Comment: Have you opened the pdf maybe?

Comment: @Glostas..the problem is pdf is not created.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yep...there was no write permission in the folder. works now ! BUT my second problem is why, when I use sudo python testt.py ....I get............ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testt.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
ImportError: No module named sklearn.......
 BUT no error without sudo...every module is loaded just fine